# Python optparse nargs option doesn't work with integer

Tags: python, parsing, optparse

I have a problem with the `nargs` option of `optparse`.
This is my code:

```
def main():
    #variable1 = 'Teste'
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
        print("Tool for calculating radiance and reflectance")
        print("for landsat 4,5,7 and 8 dataset.\n")
        print("Nais srl")
        print("Author: Lorenzo Bernardi\n")
        print("usage: %s\n"%sys.argv[0])
        print("-d, --directory  Mandatory. Directory of landsat dataset. Eg. C:\mydir\LT51900311984170XXX05")
        print("-p, --process    Mandatory. Options: [rad, ref or radref] to process radiance, reflectance or both. Default: rad")
        print("-l, --series     Mandatory. Options: [4,5,7 or 8] to specify the Landsat series")
        print("-s, --sensor     Mandatory. Options: [LC, LO, LE, LT] to specify the sensor. Eg. LE=Landsat ETM+")
        print("-b, --bands      Optional. Bands to process")
        print("-o, --output     Optional. Directory where will be saved the radiance and/or reflectance layers")
        print("-v,              Optional. Leave out the end-user control on bands under processing")

        sys.exit(option_error())
    else:
        usage = "usage: %prog [options] "
        parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)

        parser.add_option("-d", "--directory", dest="directory", action="store", type="string", \
                          help="complete path of landsat product folder: mydir/filename/")

        parser.add_option("-p", "--process", dest="operation", action="store", type="choice", \
                          help="process requested: radiance, reflectance, both", choices=['rad', 'ref', 'radref'], default='rad')

        parser.add_option("-l", "--series", dest="satellite", action="store", type="choice", \
                          help="Landsat series:4, 5, 7, 8", choices=['4', '5', '7', '8'])

        parser.add_option("-s", "--sensor", dest="sensor", action="store", type="choice", \
                          help="sensor acronymous, for example LO for Landsat OLI, or LE for Landsat ETM+, etc..", choices=['LC', 'LO', 'LE', 'LT'], default=None)

        parser.add_option("-o", "--output",   dest="output", type="string", \
                help="Directory of output raster. \n \
                    Unless specified, output directory will be workDirectory/results/datafolder/. \n \
                    If specified, the output directory wil be mydirectory/results/filename/rad (and/or ref)/", default=None)

        parser.add_option("-x", action="store_true", dest="bool", help="activate iterative radiance and/or reflectance computation for all the bands", default=False)

        parser.add_option("-b", "--bands", dest="bands", action="store", type=int, \
                          help="bands to process", nargs='*', default=None)

        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

I need to be able to use the code as:

```
bla bla bla -b 1 2 3
```

or

```
bla bla bla -b 1
```

or without -b flag (case default).

The error is:

```
   C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract>LandsatTMroutine_RadiometricCorrection_1.0.py-d "C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract\LC81910312015198LGN00" -p rad -l 8 -s  LC -b 1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract\LandsatTMroutine_RadiometricCorrection_1.0.py", line 1205, in <module>
  main()
  File "C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract\LandsatTMroutine_RadiometricCorrection_1.0.py", line 780, in main
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\optparse.py", line 1386, in parse_args
  stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\optparse.py", line 1430, in _process_args
  self._process_short_opts(rargs, values)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\optparse.py", line 1521, in _process_short_opts
  if len(rargs) < nargs:
  TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

Can someone suggest some solutions?

Comment: Use `type="int"`, not `type=int`, like the example in the documentation, and *exactly* what you do for all other options. But you may want to convert to `argparse`, since `optparse` is deprecated. Also, `argparse` does allow for `type=int`. Also, I think that `optparse` itself will output a full help message if you don't supply mandatory arguments; that's why you have help and usage message. Besides, you shouldn't really have *mandatory* *options*, that's a contradiction (though, `argparse` has a `required` keyword for this kind of thing).

Comment: @Evert, that is incorrect, as _optparse_ supports specifying `type=int`. However, it doesn't support specifying `nargs='*'`, as detailed in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33915578/3903832).

Comment: @Yoel That's correct, though both the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#standard-option-types) and the (built-in) help for the `Option` class don't mention this; `optparse` is just liberal in what it accepts.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure of it myself but I've tested it and saw that it works due to [this code excerpt](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/optparse.py#L648). I also noticed that switching `type=int` to `type="int"` doesn't solve the issue in hand while replacing `nargs='*'` with `nargs=1` does.

Answer (score 0):

The `optparse` module doesn't support specifying `'*'` as a valid value for the `nargs` argument. An integer must be specified, as implied by the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.nargs):

> `Option.nargs` (default: 1)
>
> How many arguments of type `type` should be consumed when this option is seen. If > 1, `optparse` will store a tuple of values to `dest`.

However, [the `argparse` module does support it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> `'*'`. All command-line arguments present are gathered into a list.

Furthermore, [since version 2.7 the `optparse` module is deprecated in favor of the `argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html):

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the argparse module.

The `argparse` module also supports specifying [custom help and usage messages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#help), relieving one of the need to print them himself.